# Is it possible to use a UICollectionView within a today extension?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, today-extension

I've done pretty much exactly the same code as in my main app, but all I get in the notification centre is a black image of nothing?

Maybe you can't use a uicollectionview in a today extension?

Thanks for your help

Here is the view controller file, I'm not sure what is helpful and what isn't, so I've included the majority of the file.

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding,     UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIScrollViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var datesArray: [String] = []
var sinceLabelArray: [String] = []
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.datesArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("saveddates") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    self.sinceLabelArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedsincelabels") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    collectionView.delegate = self;

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.datesArray.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int   {
    return 1
}

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    self.collectionView.reloadData()

}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell

    cell.dayCount.text = dayCount(self.datesArray[indexPath.item])
    cell.sinceOrUntilLabel.text = daysSinceOrUntil(self.datesArray[indexPath.item])
    cell.eventLabel.text = self.sinceLabelArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

// For dayCountLabel.text
func dayCount (dayCount: String) -> String{
    let day = dayCount
    let date2 = NSDate()
    //let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"
    let date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day)!
    let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    let difference = String("\(abs(diffDateComponents.day))")
    return difference
}

// For daySinceOrUntilLabel.text
func daysSinceOrUntil (daySince: String) -> String {
    let day = daySince
    let date2 = NSDate()
    //let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"
    let date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day)!
    let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

    if date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending  {
        let text: String = "Days Until"
        return text
    } else if date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
        let text: String = "Days Since"
        return text
    } else {
        return "Days"
    }
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    //let kWhateverHeightYouWant = 200
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, collectionView.bounds.size.height)
}


func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
}
```

}

Comment: When you use APIs that are not available for WatchKit extensions, your extension doesn't compile. So you are doing something wrong. We can't help you unless you post some code though.

Comment: Ok, added code :)

Comment: How is your collection view getting its size?

Comment: Through Xcode's IB